# Adding " inside a apend to to script

Tags: vbscript

In using a script to edit a text reg... The part I'm trying to change is inside "" when I run the script in it's own it changes the text inside the "" but when I add it to the rest of my script it del's the whole reg???

Is there a way of adding the "" to replace??

What i'm trying to replace is...

```
Some text
some text
some more text
"Some text"    "ENTER_USERNAME_HERE"
some text
some text
some text
"Some Text"   "ENTER_PASSWORD_HERE"

etc
etc
```

DIMS etc at the top of my script over 1300 line to to much to add... 
Storenumber is in input box at the start, likewise Password

```
Sub SUB_Password
    If (fso.FileExists("     Some File   ")) then
        File = "     Some File    "
        Set objOtF = fso.OpenTextFile(AutoLog, 1)
        content = objOtF.ReadAll
        objOtF.Close
        name = "ENTER_USERNAME_HERE"
        Set objOtF = fso.OpenTextFile(AutoLog, 2)
        objOtF.Write Replace(content, name , StoreNumber)

        objOtF.Close

        AutoLog = "     Some File   "
        Set objOtF = fso.OpenTextFile(AutoLog, 1)
        content = objOtF.ReadAll
        objOtF.Close
        pass = "ENTER_PASSWORD_HERE"
        Set objOtF = fso.OpenTextFile(AutoLog, 2)
        objOtF.Write Replace(content, pass , Password)
        objOtF.Close

        MsgBox " Some File is Complete.", vbOKonly+vbInformation+vbSystemModal
        set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(DestDir &  "Install "&MyDate& ".log", Appendtxt)
        oFile.WriteLine "Some File Password has been updated to " & Password
        oFile.WriteLine "Some File User Name has been updated to " & StoreNumber
        oFile.Close
        obj.Run """   Some File """
        wscript.sleep 5000
        obj.Run """ Some File """

    Else
        MsgBox "Some File does not exist!" , vbOKOnly+vbExclamation+vbSystemModal , "System File Missing"
        set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(DestDir &  "Install "&MyDate& ".log", Appendtxt)
        oFile.WriteLine "Some File does not exist"
        oFile.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like next:

```
' VB Script Document
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286417/adding-inside-a-apend-to-to-script
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName

'next assignment substitutes the "... ReadAll ..." code snippet
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & _
    "some text"  & vbNewLine & _
    "some more text"  & vbNewLine & _
    """Some text""    ""ENTER_USERNAME_HERE"""  & vbNewLine & _
    "some text"  & vbNewLine & _
    """Some Text""   ""ENTER_PASSWORD_HERE"""  & vbNewLine & _
    "etc"  & vbNewLine

Dim pass: pass = """ENTER_PASSWORD_HERE"""
Dim name: name = """ENTER_USERNAME_HERE"""

Dim StoreNumber: StoreNumber = "StoreNumber"
Dim Password: Password = "Password"

Wscript.Echo strResult & vbNewLine & _
    Replace( Replace( strResult, name, StoreNumber), pass, Password) 
Wscript.Quit
```